# Bootstrap's panel and vectorial image, hide everything that isn't inside panel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a vectorial SVG image, this is greater than my panel width, I would, through CSS -or something smarter-, hide everything that is not contained inside the panel. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jCORDaEtxWnuUu1tHXHM)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Timeline 
  </div>
  <div ui-view="timeline" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="panel-body ng-scope">
      <div id="target1">
        <div class="chronoline-wrapper chronoline-draggable">
          <div class="chronoline-canvas" style="height: 180px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 50px;">
              <! -- SVG related tags -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a `overflow: hidden` for your canvas? I adapted your plunk to handle the overflow for the canvas and positioning of the left/right elements. [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/QreaJCrfdNnlUZfgwAE1)